# MPAndroidChart can we have legends' text in different colors

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Can we have text of legends with different colors? I am able to set different colors to legends but not to text.

Answer (score 1):

Having different text colors for the legend labels is currently **not supported**. You will have to customize / modify the library to achieve that.